# STM32 DWT cycle counter (CYCCNT) surprising behavior (rust)

Tags: rust, arm, embedded, stm32

I'm attempting to benchmark a number of functions destined for embedded use (STM743 arm cortex m7 microcontroller). All of the code is written in Rust. To benchmark my functions, I'm using the DWT CYCCOUNT (cycle counter) to count the number of processor clock cycles required for each of these functions to execute. I then display the count on the host computer with semihosting. I'm seeing results that depend on changes in the code that I don't believe should have an effect. Here's the code I'm using

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use panic_halt as _;
use cortex_m::peripheral::{Peripherals, DWT};
use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use cortex_m_semihosting::hprintln;
use core::f32::consts::PI;

use trig_lib::{sin, cos, atan2};

const U32_MAX: u32 = 4_294_967_295u32;

macro_rules! op_cyccnt_diff {
    ( $( $x:expr )* ) => {
        {
            let before = DWT::get_cycle_count();
            $(
                let res = $x;
            )*
            let after = DWT::get_cycle_count();
            let diff =
                if after >= before {
                    after - before
                } else {
                    after + (U32_MAX - before)
                };
            (res, diff)
        }
    };
}

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let mut peripherals = Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    peripherals.DWT.enable_cycle_counter();
    let mut theta: f32 = 0.;
    let dtheta: f32 = 2. * PI / 10.6;

    loop {
        let (res, diff) = op_cyccnt_diff!(sin(theta));
        // test 1
        hprintln!("  sin({:.6})={:.6}: {}", theta, res, diff).unwrap();
        // test 2
        // hprintln!("  sin={:.6}: {}", res, diff).unwrap();

        theta += dtheta;
        if theta > 2. * PI {
            theta -= 2. * PI;
        }
    }
}
```

As you probably guessed, `sin`, `cos`, and `atan2` are the trigonometric functions I'm benchmarking. I've only shown the test for `sin` here. I don't believe their implementation is critical to this question and their interface is standard.

If I use `// test 1` I get something like:

```
  sin(0.000000)=0.000000          : 101
  sin(0.592753)=0.559139          : 171
  sin(1.185507)=0.927135          : 164
  sin(1.778260)=0.978837          : 140
  sin(2.371013)=0.697104          : 140
  sin(2.963767)=0.177065          : 147
  sin(3.556520)=-0.403504         : 172
  sin(4.149273)=-0.846134         : 179
  sin(4.742027)=-0.999605         : 172
  sin(5.334780)=-0.813040         : 172
  sin(5.927534)=-0.348535         : 172
  sin(0.237102)=0.235117          : 164
  sin(0.829855)=0.738394          : 164
  sin(1.422608)=0.989249          : 171
  sin(2.015362)=0.903282          : 140
  sin(2.608115)=0.508991          : 140
```

However, if I use `// test 2` I get something like:

```
  sin=0.000000          : 99
  sin=0.559139          : 121
  sin=0.927135          : 121
  sin=0.978837          : 122
  sin=0.697104          : 122
  sin=0.177065          : 122
  sin=-0.403504         : 151
  sin=-0.846134         : 151
  sin=-0.999605         : 158
  sin=-0.813040         : 151
  sin=-0.348535         : 151
  sin=0.235117          : 121
  sin=0.738394          : 121
  sin=0.989249          : 121
  sin=0.903282          : 122
  sin=0.508991          : 122
```

The difference is whether I print the `theta` value. The results appear to indicate that not printing the theta value requires fewer clock cycles than printing it. However, the only statement between getting the beginning and ending cycle counts is `let res = sin(theta);`, so I don't see why printing `theta` has any effect on the result. Moreover, if I replace the `hprintln!` statement with `hprintln!("{}", diff).unwrap();` I get even lower results:

```
51
66
66
94
92
68
74
74
68
68
68
68
68
66
117
117
74
74
68
68
68
68
```

Is my setup somehow flawed? Or, am I not measuring what I think I'm measuring? Why does changing `hprintln!` change the cycle count result? Is there a way to perform this test such that the result only depends on the number of clock cycles required to compute `sin(theta)`?

I've tried looking at the disassembly, but the compiler inlines a lot of functions and so it's difficult to map instructions to source code.

---

## Edit

I tried wrapping the cycle count code in a compiler fence like so:

```rust
compiler_fence(Ordering::Acquire);
let before = DWT::get_cycle_count();
$(
    let res = $x;
)*
let after = DWT::get_cycle_count();
compiler_fence(Ordering::Release);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have an effect.

---

## Edit 2

I've moved the I/O out of the loop to attempt to separate the code I'm benchmarking with the displayed output. The relevant change is

```rust
    let mut i: usize = 0;
    let mut theta_log: [f32; ITER] = [0.; ITER];
    let mut sin_res_log: [f32; ITER] = [0.; ITER];
    let mut sin_diff_log: [u32; ITER] = [0; ITER];

    let mut cos_res_log: [f32; ITER] = [0.; ITER];
    let mut cos_diff_log: [u32; ITER] = [0; ITER];

    while i < ITER {
        let (res, diff) = op_cyccnt_diff!(sin(theta));
        theta_log[i] = theta;
        sin_res_log[i] = res;
        sin_diff_log[i] = diff;

        // let (res, diff) = op_cyccnt_diff!(cos(theta));
        // cos_res_log[i] = res;
        // cos_diff_log[i] = diff;

        theta += dtheta;
        if theta > 2. * PI {
            theta -= 2. * PI;
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    for i in 0..ITER {
        hprintln!("  sin({:.6})={:.6}          : {}", theta_log[i], sin_res_log[i], sin_diff_log[i]).unwrap();
        // hprintln!("  cos({:.6})={:.6}          : {}", theta_log[i], cos_res_log[i], cos_diff_log[i]).unwrap();
        // hprintln!("----------------------------").unwrap();
    }

    loop {
    }
```

The output for just the sine is all 2's and a few 8's (this seems too low...) and the output when the cosine part is uncommented is back up in the 100s.

Comment: I assume you are compiling in release mode. In that case the compiler is allowed to reorder instructions during optimization. It is possible that part of the instructions generated by the `hprintln` call may be moved before the `let after = DWT::get_cycle_count();`.

Comment: Have you considered adding appropriate compiler fences (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/sync/atomic/fn.compiler_fence.html)) before and after the measurement?

Comment: @Jmb, I am. Is there any way to selectively prevent anything else from going between the `let before` and `let after`? Wouldn’t this also mean it’s possible some of the sine computation could happen outside this interval? If that’s the case this benchmark is essentially meaningless... I only care about this metric for optimized code, so compiling with optimizations off doesn’t help.

Comment: @L.Riemer I had not but that looks very promising! Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: When all else fails, look at the assembly output of each and also note if the code is aligned on cache well for each.  You say you looked at the assembly, but now you need to try and see the differences.  I'd also not ever attempt to include I/O in a profile unless you are profiling the I/O.  Output to results to a buffer and print when complete to isolate that away.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I've changed the code to move I/O out of the benchmarking loop (see Edit 2 for details). In terms of looking at the assembly, I've tried looking at the disassembly but am having trouble matching source code to instructions with all the inlining. Do you suggesting diffing the output for these changes? Any other strategies?

Comment: Tried compiling your code with rust compiler explorer to see the output and it won't compiler as it doesn't know about `cortex_m` and the other containers.

Comment: A lot of factors here including how the time measurement actually happens.  Alignment can play a roll, often does with these mcus.  Your clock rate and flash wait states if any (the m7 based ones may not have additional wait states).  the stm32 flash prefetch/cache thing, etc.  end of the day you need to be looking heavily at the asm and alignment of the code.  not sure stm32's support this but do you have the i or d cache on in the cortex-m?  you building for armv7-m or generic thumb?  as mentioned dont want any debug settings, want release code, optimized...

Comment: Because benchmarking is so easy to manipulate the results are often BS.  So be careful with both your test and assumptions of the results.   Changing code elsewhere in the project but certainly within the function surrounding the test or within the same file can affect the results, so again...look at the compiler output.  ideally turn it into asm/machine code wrap that in a very tight time sample solution (a single instruction in the code under test, certainly not a function call).  see if it has alignment sensitivity if so what.  likewise the library functions (sin, etc) and how they respond

Comment: is the compiler simply pre-computing the results based on the test for certain incantations of the code?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @old_timer. It sounds like there's no way around really digging into the assembly and possibly writing parts of it manually (at least the cycle counts and the benchmarked function, so that it's not executing anything else between the cycle count queries). As for pre-computing, I've tried to design this so that isn't possible. For instance, `theta` increments in a way such that it will take a long time to repeat. I've recently changed to code to only execute a certain number of times, but before I didn't specify a break condition so I don't think precomputation was possibl

Comment: at least in your initial example everything is there, no user input, so a compiler could certainly resolve the math at compile time instead of runtime, arguably it shouldnt assume that it knows what sin() does, but have seen at least gnu tools do things like that.  unlikely here, but technically possible.  when you moved to a table and went from 100+ to a few cycles that smells like it, but would have to dig deeper, I recently tried rust and along with another commenter could not get it to build for cortex-m so gave up...so cant help here.

Comment: you can keep going without assembly/machine code, if the results are consistent and within a window as you add and remove code near or within the code under test, then you can start to build confidence that that number will remain, but as in this case as the numbers vary have to dig deeper.

Comment: you mentioned semihosting, you definitely want to stop/remove that for a test, likewise if this is under an rtos then expect results to vary just from that.

Comment: What's the problem with semihosting? Sure it's slow, but any specific reason why it would affect this test? What should I use instead to get the data? ITM?